# qml mousearea overlab not work in hoverenable mode

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

my problem is that mouseArea does not pass hover events. how can i fix this problem? in other words i want print 1 and 2 together in follow example.thanks.

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true
    preventStealing: true
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onPositionChanged: console.log("1")
}
MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true
    preventStealing: true
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onPositionChanged: {
        console.log("2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`propagateComposedEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop) only works for `clicked`, `doubleClicked` and `pressAndHold` events:

> This property holds whether composed mouse events will automatically
>   propagate to other MouseAreas that overlap with this MouseArea but are
>   lower in the visual stacking order. By default, this property is
>   false.
>
> MouseArea contains several composed events: clicked, doubleClicked and
>   pressAndHold. These are composed of basic mouse events, like pressed,
>   and can be propagated differently in comparison to basic events.

You could define your own custom `QQuickItem` that installs an event filter on the `MouseArea`, or alternatively just notify the other `MouseArea` about the hover events manually.